# How to scale SVG proportionally

Tags: svg

I've exported an SVG from Illustrator and would like to set the height of the SVG and have the width scale proportionally.

Here's the example SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 20 10">
        <path fill="#124C92" d="M20,7c0,1.65-1.35,3-3,3H3c-1.65,0-3-1.35-3-3V3c0-1.65,1.35-3,3-3h14c1.65,0,3,1.35,3,3V7z" />
</svg>
```

If I only set the height, the SVG width is set to 100%.

So far I've been unable to find a solution that doesn't require me to set both the height *and* width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method 1**

Set the height to what you want.  Then set the width to something much greater than the proportional width would ever be.  That's to stop the renderer automatically reducing the height to fit the width.

```
<svg height="100px" width="1000px" ... >
```

However, by default, that will cause the content to be centred way off to the right, so you will also need to set a suitable `preserveAspectRatio` value.

```
<svg height="100px" width="1000px" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" ... >
```

**Method 2**

Set both the height an width to the desired height.  Set the `preserveAspectRatio` to one with `slice` and set the `overflow` to `visible`.

```
<svg height="100px" width="100px" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" overflow="visible" ... >
```

This approach may not be suitable for some situations.  For example, if you are embedding in HTML, the 'incorrect' size may result in the layout being wrong.  Though it should work for standalone situations.