# How to scale inline SVG uniformly with %

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use SVG elements in a fluid context, using `%` units to set the size proportional to the container.

If you include an SVG design like an image it works just like an image:

```
<img class="img-svg" src="box.svg" />
```

You can use CSS to easily scale it proportionally with stuff like this:

```
.img-svg { width:100%; height: auto; }
```

### BUT

If you use inline SVG, everything changes...

```
<svg class="inline-svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="...">
    ...
</svg>
```

This WON'T work:

```
.inline-svg { display:block; width:100%; height: auto; }
```

If you do this it will expand the SVG's box to 100% but all the elements inside it wills stay the same size. Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s_d_p/jA62R/

What's the right way to do this so that the contents inside the SVG scale up/down uniformly?

Note1: I'm looking for a CSS/SVG solution. Not a javascript hack.

NOte2: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589175/how-to-scale-svg-proportionally) but it relies on fixed `px` units.

Comment: preserveAspectRatio only has an effect if a viewBox is specified.

Comment: @RobertLongson Good catch. I left it out of my example, but it's there in my real code and not working. Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems to work in chrome for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9K9b9/

Comment: @Matthias That demo also works in FF 28.0

Answer (score 4):

I'm still getting my head around this, but here's the best I've come up with so far...

#### css

```
.svg {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

#### svg

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="...">
...
</svg>
```

The CSS needs to set the display to block because the default for SVG is `inline` (not sure why). Then you can scale it's boundary like a div.

The way you get **the contained svg nodes** to play nicely *also* is by using the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute. As Robert pointed out in a comment above, the preserveAspectRatio attribute doesn't work if you don't have a `viewBox` attribute as well.

It's worth reading more about [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) here because there a lot if different values which will determine how the scaled elements interact with the surrounding space if the dimensions are not the same. For example, if your SVG is a short wide rectangle and your container is a tall skinny rectangle, what should the browser do with the extra space to make it fit?

[Be careful! The browser defaults for `preserveAspectRatio` differ a lot!]

Comment: Good solution. (I used this in an Anki deck.) Of note, I think that some of the space and scaling elements might work better with "display: inline-block", which would make the SVG act like a true "img" element instead of always trying to take surrounding space.

Answer (score 2):

you can apply a `svg` transform to the contents of the SVG tag. or you can use the CSS3 `transform` method as well.

```
.svg {width:100%; display:block;
transform:scale(5); 
-webkit-transform:scale(5); 
-moz-transform:scale(5); 
-ms-transform:scale(5); 
-o-transform:scale(5);
}

<svg class="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewbox="0 0 102 102">
<g transform="scale(0.5)">
/*rest code will come inside this.*/
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is your working Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/jA62R/10/

Comment: I may not be understanding your answer, but it's not clear how this helps me to scale an inline `svg` relative to the container width.

Comment: The second example (transform directly in SVG) was useful for me: it can be combined like `<g transform="scale(1.5) translate(0, -30)"> (...) </g>` etc.